# return values from two nested loops

Tags: php, loops

I have a while loop nested in another while loop. The first while will give me 5 elements, and for each element I have to go to the second while and get 2 elements.

The problem is I have to return all 10 values to a function.

How can I make it?

I tried to merge two arrays but it didn't work.

```
function ShowCustomers()
{
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
    {
        while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
        {
            $res = array($row2['f_name'], $row3['name'], $row3['s_name']);
            $res1 = array_merge($res1,$res);
        }
    }
    return $res1;
}
```

Comment: it looks like you're getting results from 2 different queries? why not just join them into 1 query and return both at once?

Comment: even if i join the two query i will not solve the problem, i need to merge more than one array in one array.

Comment: you could try merging them on array_keys inside a foreach statement maybe?

Comment: ok, but then how can i get to the value in the inner array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is put all the results into one array and return it, you can use `array_push()`, or the shorthand: `$your_array[] = ...`:

```
function ShowCustomers()
{
    $result_array = array();
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
    {
        while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
        {
            $res = array($row2['f_name'], $row3['name'], $row3['s_name']);
            $result_array[] = $res;
        }
    }
    return $result_array;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean inner array, the `f_name`, etc? you would iterate through $result_array, or to access directly, it'll be something like $result_array[0]['f_name']

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare $res1 outside the scope of your loops so that it keeps its value after each iteration:

```
function ShowCustomers()
{
    $res1 = array();
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
    {
        while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
        {
            $res = array($row2['f_name'], $row3['name'], $row3['s_name']);
            $res1 = array_merge($res1,$res);
        }
    }
    return $res1;
}
```